# JavaScript: Find in array all values with substrings of array

Tags: javascript, object, filter, include, indexof

I have two arrays; one with substrings and the other with objects.

I would like to obtain an array of objects where those objects contain any of the substrings in the substrings array.

So far I have tried to use `filter` and `findIndex`. Each approach works if a substring is identical. In this case, even `indexOf` was not working. I am not javascript guy, so probably I am doing something wrong.

**Script**

```
  var strings = ['12', 'sv', 'eli', '23', '34'];

  var data = [
    {
      a: 349531284734,
      b: "sv123eippppppeli",
      c: "aaabbbccc"
    },
    {
      a: 1111123333312,
      b: "ccccccccccccs2222",
      c: "aaabbbccc"
    },
    {
      a: 2222234,
      b: "elllllllla",
      c: false
    },
  ];


  // attempt 1

  var results = data.filter(arr =>
    Object.keys(arr).some(key => {
      return String(arr[key]).toLowerCase().includes(strings) // or indexOf
    })
  );


  // attempt 2 with only one data index

  var obj = Object.values(data[0]);
  var results = strings.some(s => obj.includes(s)) // or indexOf or findIndex;
```

**Explanation**

In this example with the given substrings, only `data[0]` is a match because it contains at least on of the substrings in the `strings` array.

How can I make this work without using a "for loop"?

Thanks

Comment: what is the expected output for the given input?

Comment: it needs to return matched object. So, if data contains strings from array it needs to return. If substring is ``['aa', 'bb']`` and object is ``{a: 1, b: "oo", c: "aabb"}`` it needs to return that object.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes  Though to that effect, String.prototype.includes expects the argument to be another string, not an array of strings

Comment: @Taplar include should work also, as it is demonstrated by Dacre Denny in answer.

Comment: @Taplar ah, yes. Sorry. My mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution that avoids the need for "for-loop" syntax would be to `filter()` each object of `data` by a predicate that checks if any value (of the current item being filtered) contains any one of the values of the `strings` array.

In code, this can be expressed as:

```js
var strings = ['12', 'sv', 'eli', '23', '34'];

var data = [{
    a: 349531284734,
    b: "sv123eippppppeli",
    c: "aaabbbccc"
  },
  {
    a: 1111123333312,
    b: "ccccccccccccs2222",
    c: "aaabbbccc"
  },
  {
    a: 2222234,
    b: "elllllllla",
    c: false
  },
];

// Local helper retruns true if case-insenstive value in strings array
const stringHasValue = (value) => strings
  .some(str => value.toLowerCase().includes(str.toLowerCase()))

// Filter each item in data array by existance of a value containing
// substring in strings array
var result = data.filter((item) => Object.values(item)
  .filter(value => typeof value === 'string')
  .some(stringHasValue, []));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Fantastic. I was close, but not that close. Thanks again.

Comment: Only problem with your code is that if i am creating array of substrings on input type and after creation initiating your code, somehow it resets and older values is being ignored. ``var strings = this.value.toLowerCase().split(' ').filter(Boolean)`` but thats a bit offtopic i think.